# Rails and Devise: custom mail_sender based on current domain name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a Rails application with multiple domains. Inside `config/initializers/devise.rb` I've setup the `mail_sender` as shown above:

```
config.mailer_sender = Proc.new { request.host.include?('somedomain') ? "noreply@somedomain.com" : "noreply@theotherdomain.com" }
```

But I don't have access to the variable `request`, neither any other helper from the ApplicationController. Have you any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: request and response are performed by controller `request` is accessible from controller not outside of controller so in initializes it is not a valid declaration it is method of Actioncontroller::Base Returns an ActionDispatch::Request instance that represents the current request. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9a64ffc0c77c2b614401fad665ae2edb33c754a7/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb#L176

Comment: Any news on that one?

Answer (score 1):

In application_controller.rb

```
before_filter :site_smtp

def site_smtp
 if request.domain == "blabla.com"
    Devise.setup do |config|
      config.mailer_sender = "custom@blabla.com"
    end    
 end
end
```

Comment: Pretty sure this method is not threadsafe. So in a multithreaded setup, this will have some race conditions on what the sender will be.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set the sender in your mailer. That means you will have to override the devise mailer for that. A simple solution would be to use the following (additionally I added application_helper's view helper to the mailer):

```
# in config/initializers/devise.rb
config.mailer = "CustomDeviseMailer"

# app/mailers/custom_devise_mailer.rb
class CustomDeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
helper :application
default from: request.host.include?('somedomain') ? "noreply@somedomain.com" : "noreply@theotherdomain.com"
```

hope that helps you out

Comment: At the moment, I don't have a custom DeviseMailer controller. Should I setup one? thanks

Comment: I would highly recommend it - its as easy as it is in the example.

Comment: Could you eventually accept the answer, vote it up or at least give feedback whether you could manage to solve your problem.

Comment: @collimarco but doesn't ActionMailer inherit from [`AbstractController::Base`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html)